# Can I fix this Hard drive in linux?

Tags: hard-drive, windows, external-hdd, mass-storage

I have a a 2TB Seagate HDD that I use on my Windows PC but it suddenly stopped showing up on any PC at all, not even in disk manager. Can this hard drive be recognized in Linux? Can I fix it in Linux? Please help Ive got tons of work in it. Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to know if your disk will be recognized until you try it. Linux is not magic - if your drive is dead or dying in Windows, then it will still be dead or dying in Linux.

Comment: Suggest you ask in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com for an LiveUSB package designed for disk data recovery.  https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-retrieve-windows-files-using-a-linux-live-cd/ is a good thing to read to get a head start.

Comment: If you're lucky you can use `smartmontools` to get the _S.M.A.R.T._ data of your drive that gives you a feedback about the status of your drive. If that doesn't work, you'd be out of luck. Use `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda1` or similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drive Recovery with ddrescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873439/drive-recovery-with-ddrescue)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, there are ways to recover data from dead HDDs. For example, if the plates are intact, but the electronics is defective, it can be swapped with a healthy HDD to recover the data, however, this is very special treatment and mind you, not cheap.

Ask some computer repair shop near you, they could help you. There are even businesses specializing on data recovery.